# Rename multiple folders with different names in Java

Tags: java

With this code, I can rename two Folders:

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
     RenameFolder  f = new RenameFolder();
     f.RenameFolder();    
   }

   private void RenameFolder()
   {
       File f1= new File("C:\\Users\\Nm\\Desktop\\Lauer");
       File f2= new File("C:\\Users\\Nm\\Desktop\\Axeler");

       try {
           if(f1.exists()) {
               f1.renameTo(f2);
               System.out.println("Folder " +f1.getName()+
                                   " was changed into " +f2.getName() +"..." );
           } else {
               f1.mkdir();
               System.out.println("Folder " +f1.getName()+ " was created..." );
           }
       } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

How can I do that when I have to rename over thousand folders with names? For example:

```
raro -> noto
mano -> kaoto
Daum -> Loeme
Gato -> Rate
Ta+To -> Mo~no
etc...
```

Comment: You can build a "dictionary" to to match the new name, and iterate over the folders finding the new name in this dictionary and renaming them

Comment: You may create a file (e.g CSV) with the current name and the future name, read the file line by line, for each line rename the given folder.

Comment: Your `RenameFolder` method should take path to original file and new name as parameters

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know how I should implement it

Comment: Neither do we given the information you've supplied. Is the problem with the actual renaming of a file or with handling thousands of folders or...? Please be more specific and also explain what your input, how do you know which folders to rename and to what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put all the folder names in an array and loop through the array to rename all folders.

```
   private void RenameFolder()
   {
       ArrayList CurrentName=new ArrayList();
       ArrayList NewName=new ArrayList();


       CurrentName.add(path);
       NewName.add(path);
       //repeat about two lines for as many folders you want.

       for(int i=0;i<CurrentName.size()-1;i++){

          File f1= new File(CurrentName.get(i));
          File f2= new File(NewName.get(i));

           try {
              if(f1.exists()) {
                 f1.renameTo(f2);
                 System.out.println("Folder " +f1.getName()+
                                   " was changed into " +f2.getName() +"..." );
            } else {
               f1.mkdir();
               System.out.println("Folder " +f1.getName()+ " was created..." );
           }
       } catch(Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       }

   }
```

Comment: Having to separate ArrayList objects that needs to be perfectly in synch isn't really the best solution.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson would be a Hashmap an option? Because file or folders name must be unique on filesystem, so multiple keys for the hashmap are unrealistic.

Comment: @reporter yes a HashMap would be a much better option or a list with Pair objects

Comment: Hallo guy, Suppose the list of folders are stored on a csv file renaming the folders in a path, how can I change this code so that all folders will be renamed.